# telegraf plugin cnosdb cannot use data from v2.4.x subscription

Tags: cnosdb

I follow the document and found that cnosdb version 2.4 does not support telegraf heterogeneous data synchronization
version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e